# How to change the value in a PHP search form (on focus / on blur)?

Tags: php, wordpress, search-form

In a search form I want to change the initial value in the search field from 'Your Search' to ' ' (none) as the user enters the search field (on focus) and to change it back to the original value when the user leaves the field without entering a search (on blur). The Boilerplate function I am using is this:

```
    function boilerplate_search_form ( $form ) {
    $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
    <div>
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __('Search for:','luchtspin') . '</label>
    <input type="search" placeholder="' . __('', 'luchtspin') . '" value="'. __('Your search','luchtspin') .'" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__('Search','luchtspin') .'" />
    </div>
    </form>';
    return $form
    }
    add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'boilerplate_search_form' );
```

I was thinking along the lines of adding the code below, but obviously I can't just throw in an if statement and that is exactly where my PHP skills stop.

```
    onfocus=if (form.value == "'. __('Your search','luchtspin') .'") {form.value = '';} onblur=if (form.value == '') {form.value = "'. __('Your search','luchtspin') .'";}
```

This is probably not too difficult. For good measure a link to the site with the search form: www.luchtspin.nl. Anyone who can assist me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery for this task

```
$("input").blur(function() {
    if($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0)
        $(this).val($(this).data('last_value'));
}).focus(function() {
    $(this).data('last_value', $(this).val());
    $(this).val("")
});
```

Comment: Seems OK, but I'd rather adapt the original Boilerplate code. That should not be too difficult would it?

Comment: Hi nicowernli, I think your solution is the most elegant for my situation (for IE6-8). Only thing is that the input field does not show the placeholder value initially. Only after entering and leaving the input field it shows up. How do I change that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well you can save the last input in a data attribute with jquery. I change the answer right now so you can see it.

Comment: Dismiss my last comment, I figured it out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute. `<input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Your Search">`

Comment: This is the right solution, but you should take a look at the placeholder polyfills on https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills to get support for older versions of IE.

Comment: Ah.. a familiar page! Thanks JustJohn, I will check it out.

Comment: On second thought I don't know if I want to add another polyfill lib (I am using PIE already). My own 'solution' (above) should work, because the subscription form on my site works that way. I am only not able to put it together...